# calculus question attempt

Tags: calculus, derivatives

find the maximum value of the function $$y = 15 \sin x -8 \cos x $$

attempt at  a solution: 
 deriving: $y' = 15\cos x +8\sin x 
$  equating to zero and doubling by $ 1/\cos x$  (Im not sure this is allowed since if $x$ is $\pi/2 $ we might find ourselves in a bit of a trouble)  : $$0 = 15 +8\tan x $$

a few steps forward; $x=-0.344\pi$. by checking near by points we can determine its a maximum...
so final solution is $(-0.344\pi,0) max$.

I didn't get the answers right though, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you want the max or min point, you need to evaluate in the original function and the first derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y' = 15\cos x +8\sin x = 0 \iff 8\sin x = -15\cos x \implies \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = -\frac {15}{8}, $$ $$\iff \tan x = -\frac{15}{8},\;\text{provided } \;\cos x \neq 0$$

Since $\cos x = 0$ does not solve the equation, we can divide by $\cos x$ without problems.

Now, determine when $\tan x = -\frac{15}{8}$, by using the arctan function on each side of the equation. $$x = \arctan\left(-\frac {15}{8}\right)$$ and then determine all other solutions. The desired solution will be a maximum when it lies in the second quadrant, so that $\sin x > 0$, $\cos x < 0$.  This will yield the greatest value of $y$, when substituted into the original equation.

Comment: by the way the answer is 17

Comment: You need to plug the x-value at which the function is maximized (call it $x_{\text{max}})$ into the **original function** (at the top), to find $y_{\text{max}}$: $$y_{\text{max}} = 15 \sin(x_{max}) - 8\cos(x_{max})$$

Comment: wow, thanks, great explanation, got it.

Comment: You're welcome, Bak1139!

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is
$$y = 15 \sin x -8 \cos x
\\=17\{ \frac{15}{17} \sin x -\frac{8}{17} \cos x\}
\\=17\{  \sin x \cos\theta- \cos x\sin\theta\}
\\=17\sin (x-\theta)$$Then the maximum value is 17

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is essentially correct, except that in order to maximize the function you want $\sin x$ to be positive and $\cos x$ to be negative. So you want a solution for $\tan x = -15/8$ in the range $(\pi/2, \pi)$.